# VBA code to copy pivot table data and populate a field

Tags: vba, excel

i'm trying to write a script that will copy a pivot table and paste the values in another sheet.  for some reason, if I don't start the script on the az tracker sheet, the script will copy the (and fill) the wrong range.  can you see where the issue lies?

```
Sub updateazdata()
Dim wbmodel As Excel.Workbook
Set wbmodel = Workbooks("AMS")
Dim col As Long
Dim lastcol As Long
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim azurerng As Range


   wbmodel.Sheets("Az order book").PivotTables("Azpivot").PivotSelect "", xlDataandlabels
   Set rng = Selection.Offset(2, 0)
   rng.Select



   Set azrng = wbmodel.Sheets("az Tracker").Range("G4").Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count)
   azrng.Value = rng.Value

   Set azrng = azrng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    azrng.Select

    'azrng.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"



End Sub
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: My guess is that i'm not qualifying the sheet that i'm working in when i'm assigning the rng variable.  do I need to change the code to something like `set rng =  wbmodel.Sheets("Az order book").selection.offset(2,0)?`

Comment: As currently written, `Set rng = Selection.Offset(2, 0)` will be referring to the active sheet, whatever that may be.  So, yes, it is always better to qualify which sheet you are referring to.  And it is even better not to refer to `Selection` except when you are specifically designing something to work based on a cell that the user selects, and which you have no idea where that may be.  But I don't use pivot table objects enough to know whether what you are doing makes sense or not.